# Medium Sized Quiz Application, Troubles Dynamically generating Labels & RadioButtons

Tags: java, swing

So this snippet of code is from an application I'm building for my job. One window gets the user's name, then they select a category, then they take the quiz.

```
static void QuestionsWindow(){
    ProtemInservices.SetActiveQuestions();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Quiz for: " + ProtemInservices.testeeName);        
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Vector<JLabel> questions = new Vector<JLabel>();
    Vector<ButtonGroup> questionsGroup = new Vector<ButtonGroup>();
    Vector<JRadioButton> choices = new Vector<JRadioButton>();
    Vector<String> choicesString = new Vector<String>();
    frame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<ProtemInservices.ActiveQuestions.size();i++){
        choicesString = new Vector<String>();
        questions.add(new JLabel(ProtemInservices.ActiveQuestions.elementAt(i).GetQuestionText()));
        ProtemInservices.ActiveQuestions.elementAt(i).CopyChoices(choicesString);
        questionsGroup.add(new ButtonGroup());
        frame.add(questions.elementAt(i));
        for(int j=0;j<choicesString.size();j++,counter++){
            choices.add(new JRadioButton(choicesString.elementAt(j)));
            questionsGroup.elementAt(i).add(choices.elementAt(j));
            frame.add(choices.elementAt(counter));
        }
    }
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1280, 1024));

    //Display the window.
    //frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

My problem is dynamically creating RadioButtons and Labels. The labels come out as expect, but the nested loop is supposed to create a set of RadioButtons for each Label. I have only tested this with two different categories, the first creates the labels then creates the RadioButtons, but only for the first label and after it has created all other labels. The second category creates the labels as it should but the RadioButtons are real wonky, two come after the second label and another two are at the end.

[First Category GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nTJ6.png)

Any hints would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Create `JPanel` for each group, place the label and radio buttons on it, add this panel to the frame

Comment: but isn't there something wrong with my loops, if I can't ever get the first label and radio buttons together?

Comment: If there is, I can't pick it out from the out-of-context code snippet you've provided.  I tend not to use `BoxLayout`, so I'm not sure if that's the issue.

Comment: ProtemInservices.ActiveQuestions.elementAt(i).CopyChoices(choicesString);  

Is this filling your choicesString vector each time?  if not what is?

Comment: choices.add(new JRadioButton(choicesString.elementAt(j)));
            questionsGroup.elementAt(i).add(choices.elementAt(j));

So the second time through the outer loop you will be continually adding to the choices vector but only grabbing the first few as j resets each time.  How do you know you are adding the right elements from choices.  if you added two buttons to choices on each loop then the internal loop you would be taking just the first 2 each time and re-adding them to the new Questionsgroup.   Would you ever be adding the right buttons as the outer loop continues?

Comment: I understand what you mean, and I can appreciate that 500+ lines of code is hard to extrapolate from only 35 lines. With that said Peter3, the choiceString is reinitialized and set to the next question each time the outer loop runs, with choicesString = new Vector<String>(); 
ProtemInservices.ActiveQuestions.elementAt(i).CopyChoices(choicesString);

Comment: but choices isn't right? wouldn't choices eventually build up but you would still be grabbing the first 'j' choices each time to fill out your question group?

Comment: I believe you're right, I didn't understand at first. That is an issue I didn't even realize, how can I correctly count up? 
The only thing I can think to do is add another counter inside of the nested loop

Comment: That might work if the number of j's will always be the same.  if it is variable then that wouldn't work.  you could potentially keep a count of how many times j runs with an int to use as the marker.  not the smoothest way but something quick i can think of off the top of my head

Comment: Also even it it was the same number each time when j = 0 then i*j = 0 and that would lead to the same problem as before

Comment: thanks I updated this question to reflect your fix, I added the counter but I am still having the issue of only 1 set of choices showing up with all of the questions

Comment: questionsGroup.elementAt(i).add(choices.elementAt(j));

this was the line i was looking at before that is tied to j

Comment: hahaha with 2 minutes to spare before my shift is finished, you are a genius peter. Do you want to post that solution below, so i can choose it as the answer?

Comment: Sure I will just copy what you have above and change j to counter in that line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static void QuestionsWindow(){
    ProtemInservices.SetActiveQuestions();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Quiz for: " + ProtemInservices.testeeName);        
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Vector<JLabel> questions = new Vector<JLabel>();
    Vector<ButtonGroup> questionsGroup = new Vector<ButtonGroup>();
    Vector<JRadioButton> choices = new Vector<JRadioButton>();
    Vector<String> choicesString = new Vector<String>();
    frame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<ProtemInservices.ActiveQuestions.size();i++){
        choicesString = new Vector<String>();
        questions.add(new JLabel(ProtemInservices.ActiveQuestions.elementAt(i).GetQuestionText()));
        ProtemInservices.ActiveQuestions.elementAt(i).CopyChoices(choicesString);
        questionsGroup.add(new ButtonGroup());
        frame.add(questions.elementAt(i));
        for(int j=0;j<choicesString.size();j++,counter++){
            choices.add(new JRadioButton(choicesString.elementAt(j)));
            questionsGroup.elementAt(i).add(choices.elementAt(counter));
            frame.add(choices.elementAt(counter));
        }
    }
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1280, 1024));

    //Display the window.
    //frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

The logic is laid out above in the comments on how we came to this solution.